# function to write on stderr with python2 and python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm writing a program that ought to work with both python2 and python3.
For this, I would like to have a function to write to stderr that works with both python versions.

Ideal I think would be something like:

```
def writeStdErr(message):
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
        print(message, end = "", file = sys.stderr)
    else:
        sys.stderr.write(message)
```

the problem with this that python2 is, that print isn't a function, so I get

```
    print(message, end = "", file = sys.stderr)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I could get rid of this by just adding eval:

```
def writeStdErr(message):
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
        eval('print(message, end = "", file = sys.stderr)')
    else:
        sys.stderr.write(message)
```

however, I dislike this solution; I think it's general a bad idea to use eval.

Does anyone knows something better/has a better solution?

**EDIT:**

For anyone having the same problem in future, the following things seem works:

```
def writeStdErr(message):
    sys.stderr.write(message)
```

or

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
def writeStdErr(message):
    print(message, file=sys.stderr)
```

Thanks to all answers

Comment: Doesn't `sys.stderr.write(message)` work under Python 3 as well?  Why not just use that for all versions?

Comment: no sys.stderr.write does unfortunately not work under python3. Thats why I choose to check which python version is running

Comment: I just tested in versions 3.1 and 3.3, and `sys.stderr.write('foo')` worked in both.  What happens when you try to do it?

Comment: Just tested it too, your write, I had something wrong in mind

Comment: @quant : "your write": did you mean "you are right"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Python2.7, you can import the new behaviour:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

That should be the first line of code (but could go after a shebang).

Another alternative compatible with earlier versions is to create it in an external module.

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    from print_sderr3 import writeStdErr
else:
    from print_stderr2 import writeStdErr
```

where you have implemented each one accordingly.

That is to answer your question, **BUT**, you can just use `sys.stderr.write` for both. The only difference is that in Python 3 it seems to return the number of characters written. If you do it on interactive mode:

```
>>> sys.stderr.write('aaaa\n')
aaaa
5
```

You get an extra `5`, but that is just the return value.

```
>>> a = sys.stderr.write('aaaa\n')
aaaa
>>> a
5
```